# Mod_Rewrite rule -- trailing slash

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have to set 301 redirection from

```
https://domain.com
```

to

```
https://domain.com/
```

but is should be working only for main URL

I have tried example:

```
RewriteRule ^$ https://domain.com/ [L,R=301]
```

and

```
RewriteRule ^https://domain.com$ https://domain.com/ [L,R=301]
```

but it doesn't work in this way...

Comment: `https://domain.com` is same as `https://domain.com/`

Comment: I know but SEO company wants to make 301 redirection.
For them this is different domain....